# Drupal 8: Redirect from Default Taxonomy Term Page/Path to Custom Page Created in Panels/Pages

Tags: panel, redirect, drupal-8, taxonomy

I am trying to redirect the Taxonomy term path/url to a custom panels/page, I  found several posts from around the web about that and tried to implement the instructions but they did not work and I am doing something wrong. For example I tried what I thought was the closest to my situation found [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219028/create-panel-page-for-taxonomy-term-page) and in the following quote but it did not work and the Taxonomy views was already disabled in the first place on my end.

> 1. Disable the Taxonomy term view.
> 2. Set the path on the panels page to /taxonomy/term/%.
> 3. Clear cache.
> 4. View page at taxonomy/term/{tid}.
> 5. I verified that this also works with URL aliases.

Can someone provide clear directions for the following
[Pages/Panel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqHVI.png)
What do I enter in,

1. Page information
2. Page parameters
3. Page access
4. Variants: contexts
5. Variants: selection criteria

I've tried all kinds of different settings ("/taxonomy/term/{tid}", "/taxonomy/term/%", "/taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}", "/taxonomy/term/112") and changing Home>>Administration>>Configuration>>Search and metadata>>url alias settings but every link just goes back to the default taxonmy term page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. If any body needs the answer here it is.

To change the page/layout of a taxonomy term first go to page manager (Home >> Administration >> Structure ).

You might see a page called "Taxonomy Term", that's where you want to start to make changes so click on that. If not you'll have to create on page. Both can be addressed by the following steps.

This example will show you how to create and use different layout for a different term page.

1. Go to Structure > Pages (/admin/structure/page_manager) and click on Edit button under Taxonomy Term row. On the right side you will see Default
   These are variants. The Default variant at the bottom affects all the taxonomy/term pages. All other above variants overrides the Default variant using certain conditions a.k.a "Selection criteria".
2. Click the Add variant button to add a new variant.
3. Enter Label for the variant and choose "Panels" under the Type dropdown menu.
4. Choose "In-place Editor" for a Builder
5. Choose Layout for the page.
6. Enter [term:name] for Page title. This token holds the name of your taxonomy term. Now click on the Finish button, you will add block later.
7. Click on the Selection criteria.
8. Choose "Request Path" for a condition and click on the "Add condition" button.
9. Add taxonomy term page url's you wish to override (e.g. taxonomy/term/25).
10. Go to one of those pages (e.g. taxonomy/term/25) and add blocks.
11. Note that your variant must be positioned above the variant you override to work properly. Use the Reorder variants button to reorder your variants.

You can repeat this procedure if you wish to target a different terms also or a vocabulary. You can have as many variants you want.